# IIS 6 Cannot set index.php to default

Tags: php, iis

In IIS I have gone to the Documents Tab and added index.php to the top of the default list and restarted IIS but I get a page cannot be displayed.

Please let me know if there is something I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing PHP, I read instructions to set the Execute permissions to Scripts only. Changing it to Scripts and Executables got the page to redirect to index.php as default. I'm not sure if it's the content of my index.php or if needed in general, but it works.